# Cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator): this appears to be a native image

Tags: java, jackson, quarkus, objectmapper, quarkus-rest-client

I have a Java application developed using the Quarkus framework. It hits the external API using the RestClient which works fine locally, however when I create the containerized native image and deploy it to Kubernetes it gives the below error message:

```
Cannot construct instance of `com.abc.xyz.ZohoLeaveDto`: cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator): this appears to be a native image, in which case you may need to configure reflection for the class that is to be deserialized
 at [Source: (StringReader); line: 1, column: 3] (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0])**
```

```java
@Override
public List<ZohoLeaveDto> getLeaves(String token, Instant lastModifiedTime, int index, int limit) {
    log.infov(
            "Request to get leaves with last modified time: {0}, milli: {1}",
            lastModifiedTime,
            lastModifiedTime.toEpochMilli());

    try {
        token = StringUtils.isBlank(token) ? getAccessToken() : token;
        String apiResponse = zohoRestClient.getLeaves(token, index, limit,
                lastModifiedTime.toEpochMilli());
        log.infov("leave api response: {0}", apiResponse);
        objectMapper.registerModules(new ParanamerModule(), new ParameterNamesModule());
        objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
        JsonNode responseJson = objectMapper.readValue(apiResponse, JsonNode.class);
        if (responseJson.get(0).get("errorcode") != null) {
            log.errorv("Unable to get leaves from zoho due to :{0}", responseJson);
            return Collections.emptyList();
        } else {
            List<ZohoLeaveDto> leaves = objectMapper.readValue(apiResponse,
                    new TypeReference<List<ZohoLeaveDto>>() {
                    });
            log.infov("{0} leave records has been fetched successfully", leaves.size());
            return leaves;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.errorv("error in fetching leaves from zoho: {0}", e.getMessage());
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }
}
```

**ZohoLeaveDto.java**

```java
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@RegisterForReflection
public class ZohoLeaveDto {

    @Schema(example = "4106900")
    private String recordId;

    @JsonAlias("Employee ID")
    @Schema(example = "Aleo Kirb S2")
    private String employeeId;

    ...

}
```

Comment: Please specify Quarkus version.

Comment: Hi @zforgo, Quarkus version is 2.15.3.Final

Comment: Got the similar situation here when using `jsonObjectMapper.convertValue` with `TypeReference`. My environment is graalvm-jdk-21.0.2+13.1. I guess the Graalvm has to be smarter when dealing with generics.